# Lookup doesn't find a value when it should

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following sheets set up:

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIdas.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1h9c.png)

In cell H3 the formula below looks at the date above, returns the correct information, which pulls through data from a certain week on Sheet 1.
This works perfectly!

```
=INDIRECT("Data!"&LOOKUP($H$2,$A$3:$B$54)&G3+3)
```

In cell M3 the same basic formula looks at the date above (which is one week earlier), and doesn't work, even though it should!

```
=INDIRECT("Data!"&LOOKUP($M$2,$A$3:$B$54)&G3+3)
```

The date in H2 needs to be the start of the previous week and is found with the below formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY((TODAY()-7))=1, (TODAY()-7), (TODAY()-7)-WEEKDAY((TODAY()-7)-1))
```

The date in M2 is the week before that and is found with the following formula:

```
=H2-7
```

I can't understand why the formula in M3 isn't finding data I can see in the list! I've verified that Excel see's the two values as the same using the formula (which comes back as TRUE):

```
=M2=A54
```

Why isn't it finding it, and how can I fix this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble finding the correlation between the *Data* and *Assembler* sheets because of the redacted information (*which I understand*).  However, assuming the rows match up 1 for 1 across sheets, an `INDEX`/`MATCH` combo should be a "better way":

In `H3`

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$3:$A$54,MATCH($H$2,$A$3:$A$54))
```

and `M3`

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$3:$A$54,MATCH($M$2,$A$3:$A$54))
```

Comment: Thanks reasra, Index Match function looks really useful and I'll definitely be taking advantage of this. However it still returns a N/A on the second lot of data (M3). I have discovered that sorting the list of dates on the sheet Assembler in column A fixes this (however this isn't really convenient as I would need to re-sort every time new data is entered, and this needs to be idiot-proof). An ideas why the list of dates would need to be in ascending order to get a match?

Comment: Sorting shouldn't matter. Only thing I can think of is if there's duplicates in the array to match, or if the "previous week" isn't in the list. Add the third (optional) argument for Match, and see if it helps (there's only 3 choices, default is 0).